# problemas con php y porcentajes

Tags: php

tengo el siguiente problema con este fragmento de código

```
<?php 

$Rate= 4.12; //tasa en el momento USD to Bs. 1$ = 4.12 Bs
$percentage = 8; // porcentaje ganancia

$fee = ($Rate * $percentage) / 100; // comision  = 0.3296
$originalRate = $Rate;
$Rate -= $fee; // 3.79 rate ok....


// logica para Bs to USD
// rate VES to USD. 1Bs = 0,242718 USD
$Rate= 1 / 4.12; // 0,2427184466019417 ok.... 
$percentage = 8;

$fee = ($Rate * $percentage) / 100; // comision = -0.01941744
$originalRate = $Rate;
$Rate -= $fee; // 0.26213544 rate is no ok....

$r = 1 / $Rate //  3,81 //// y deberia decir 4.45  

?>
```

lo tengo documentado
en el código

alguna alma piadosa que me de una manita por favor

Comment: Se mas especifico, ¿Qué es lo que te pide el problema ?.

Comment: pues necesito convertir de una moneda a otra respetando la tasa de 4,12

Comment: En PHP 7.1.33 resulta `4.4782608695652`.

Comment: si. pero la realidad esta en que se necesita 4.5 que es la realidad

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: Haciéndolo a calculadora y ejecutando el código da `4.478260869565` no tiene pinta de ser del código, parque o no esté bien la fórmula o los parámetros de entrada

Answer (score 0):

Parece que lo que buscas es el resultado con un decimal, por tanto lo más sencillo es usar la función round de php

```
    $r = round(1/$Rate,1)
```

El primer argumento es el número a redondear y el segundo la precisión (número de decimales).
Tu código da como resultado que $r vale 4.4782608695652, pero si lo redondeas con raound() a un decimal te queda 4.5.

Comment: lo intentare... y te comento